# Cannot get xinetd to start on a RHEL server

Tags: rhel5, xinetd

When I try to execute

> /etc/init.d/xinetd start

I get the following error:

> Starting xinetd: /bin/bash: /usr/sbin/xinetd: cannot execute binary file
>                                                              [FAILED]

Also, if I check the status of xinetd, I get the following output:

> xinetd dead but subsys locked

--

Server details:

> Linux xxx.xxx.xxx.edu 2.6.18-194.11.3.el5 #1 SMP Mon Aug 23 15:49:21 EDT 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

---

> /usr/sbin/xinetd

produced:

> bash: /usr/sbin/xinetd: cannot execute binary file

--

> stat /usr/sbin/xinetd

produced:

> File: `/usr/sbin/xinetd'
>     Size: 164144          Blocks: 336        IO Block: 4096   regular file
>   Device: 802h/2050d      Inode: 392043      Links: 1
>   Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
>   Access: 2011-04-08 09:27:58.000000000 -0400
>   Modify: 2011-04-06 17:04:35.000000000 -0400
>   Change: 2011-04-06 17:06:21.000000000 -0400

Comment: Can we get teh output of file /usr/sbin/xinetd, stat /usr/sbin/xinetd, and uname -a ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file may have been damaged or is for the wrong architecture; run `file /usr/sbin/xinetd` and `rpm -V xinetd` to verify, and then proceed to reinstall the package correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that the file had been copied from a 64-bit machine, so that was the problem.